# Can we convert one User defined datatype (Child class) to another custom data type (Parent) Downcasting

Tags: c#

We can boxing (value type to object) Upcasting  , unboxing (object to value) Downcasting. 
this is posible since compiler allready know type before conversion (int to object)(object to int), Object is base class for all class in .net framework So this downcasting possible, So
Can we convert one User defined datatype (Child class) to another custom data type (Parent) Downcasting

```
class Customer
{

}

class GoldCustomer : Customer
{

}
```

Below is an “upcasting” code where the child parent class gold customer is pushed to the customer class.

```
Customer obj = new GoldCustomer();
```

Below is a sample of “downcasting” code where parent class object is tried to move to a child class object, this is not allowed in .NET.

```
GoldCustomer obj = new Customer(); // not allowed illegal
```

Comment: This is not C++, you should probably remove that tag.

Answer (score 2):

A reference type S can be implicitly converted to type T if S inherits T.

Comment: I advice to purchase book "C# Programming Lamguage" by Anders Hejlsberg, and others. It can be used as a Reference on C#.

Answer (score 1):

You can only unbox/cast `object` to `int` if that `object` actually is a boxed `int`:

```
int value = 10;
object boxedValue = (object)value;
int unboxedValue = (int)boxedValue; // works

object nonIntObject = "a string";
int unboxedValue = (int)nonIntObject; // does not work
```

And there's exactly the same thing with reference types and casting. You can explicitly cast child class to parent class only if the instance is actually downcasted child class instance (or class derived from child class).

```
Customer value = new GoldCustomer();
GoldCustomer childValue = (GoldCustomer)value; // works

Customer value = new Customer();
GoldCustomer childValue = (GoldCustomer)value; // does not work
```

Comment: That is perfect, however what i understood is like parent is like big container (GoldCustmer, SilverCustomer) that contains everything all common behavior and child is more specilized ,

Comment: Yes, you can assume that. But you have to know that downcasting does not actually change the object in memory. It just changes the way you look at it. That's why you can always cast it back to derived class.

Answer (score 0):

Customer value = new Customer();
GoldCustomer childValue = (GoldCustomer)value; // does not work
It will not work simply because childValue is a incomplete object which has only parent memory block not his part of child.

Customer value = new GoldCustomer();
GoldCustomer childValue = (GoldCustomer)value; // works
because now child object pointing its own type actually and its has full memory block part of base plus child, one more thing it can also do not it can call its own part too means child call specific property.

Child is type of base so it is possible.
Type compatibility